# rails 4 best practices for using scopes over class methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

when should i use a scope over a class method? or is it just a matter of preference.

Comment: Last I read class methods are preferred with the birth of AREL.

Comment: You should be using scopes, because the are always chainable, class methods are not.  http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/